# Repeat function as long as fail condition is not met

Tags: python, python-3.x, multidimensional-array, do-while

I am creating a python roguelike which utilises proceduraly created dungeon maps. I decided to achieve this using pythons' lists. I created a 2d list (matrix) to use as the map and used 0's to signify blank space. To make "rooms" inside the dungeon I used randomly generated variables to determine a random row and column for the rooms top right corner, and replaced the 0's with 1's (to signify rooms) using for loops and iterating over a random number of rows and columns:

Example Grid beforehand:

```py
00000000000000
00000000000000
00000000000000
00000000000000
00000000000000
00000000000000
```

Example Grid after room is created and inserted:

```py
00000000000000  or  00000000000000 etc
01111000000000      00000111111000
01111000000000      00000111111000
01111000000000      00000000000000
00000000000000      00000000000000
00000000000000      00000000000000
```

Code with function to create grid, create and insert room, and print grid:

```py
import random

rand_row = random.randint(0,25)
rand_column = random.randint(0,25)
room_height = random.randint(7,15)
room_length = random.randint(7,15)

def create_grid():
    global grid
    grid = [[0 for column in range (50)] for row in range(50)]
    create_room()

def create_room():
    global grid
    print (f"Room generated is of length {room_length} and height {room_height}")
    print (f"Room placed randomly in row {rand_row} and column {rand_column}")
    print (" ")

    if room_height > 0:
        for point in grid[rand_row]:
            for each_number in range(room_length):
                for increment in range(room_height):
                    grid[rand_row+increment][rand_column+each_number] = 1


def print_grid():
    global grid
    for row in grid:
        print(" ".join(map(str,row)))

create_grid()
print_grid()
```

What I dont know how to do, is generate multiple rooms while making sure that none of them overlap. I attempted to make a check subroutine that returned a boolean value dependant on whether the randomly generated values for the rooms size and location would work (If there was overlap with another room, it wouldnt work):

```py
def check_if_space_taken():
    global space_is_taken
    global grid
    for each_row in range(rand_row,room_height+rand_row):
        if any(1 in each_row for each_row in grid):
            space_is_taken = True
        else:
            space_is_taken = False
```

However, I don't know how to utilise this and i'm not even sure if it works. I also created a function that changes all the room values:

```py
def change_room_params():
    cfg.first_row = random.randint(0,50)
    cfg.first_column  = random.randint(0,50)
    cfg.temp_room_height = random.randint(5,20)
    cfg.temp_room_length = random.randint(5,20)
```

But I know that the process of checking could take forever if the random numbers keep on giving values that dont work.

To summarise, how do I create new parameters for a new room and check if there is overlap between rooms: thus creating new values and repeating the process if there is overlap or creating the room if there is no overlap and subsequently repeating the process until there is definitely no space for anymore rooms.

Thanks for your help in advance. Ive posted this question before but deleted and re-did it for more detail. I am not very experienced with python or programming in general so suggestions to improve the efficiency of my task is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An improvement would be to use [numpy](https://www.numpy.org/) [arrays](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array.html) instead of python lists. Especially when you have huge maps.

Then you could use the [skimage draw module](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.draw.html#skimage.draw.polygon) to draw polygons or in your case rectangles. To check if a to rooms intercept you could check if at any point of the new room already a 1 is in the array. This checking shouldn't take to long. Especially when you do it only once. To avoid an endless loop. You could set a high maximum iteration. And if you don't enough rooms just zero the array and redo the process.

I created a code that should work. If you have any questions feel free to ask them in the comments.

### Method withoud numpy and skimage

```
def insert_room(data, row, col) -> bool:
    if row + ROOM_HEIGHT > MAP_HEIGHT or col + ROOM_LENGTH > MAP_WIDTH or row < 0 or col < 0:
        return False
    # This method assumes that all rooms are equal in size
    if (data[row][col] == 1 or
            data[row + ROOM_HEIGHT - 1][col] == 1 or
            data[row][col + ROOM_LENGTH - 1] == 1 or
            data[row + ROOM_HEIGHT - 1][col + ROOM_LENGTH - 1] == 1):
        return False
    for r in range(row, row + ROOM_HEIGHT):
        for c in range(col, col + ROOM_LENGTH):
            data[r][c] = 1
    return True
```

**Allowing all room sizes**

```
def insert_room(data, row, col) -> bool:
    if row + ROOM_HEIGHT > MAP_HEIGHT or col + ROOM_LENGTH > MAP_WIDTH or row < 0 or col < 0:
        return False
    # Can room be added
    for r in range(row, ROOM_HEIGHT):
        if any(data[r][col:col+ROOM_LENGTH]):
            return False
    # Add room
    for r in range(row, row + ROOM_HEIGHT):
        for c in range(col, col + ROOM_LENGTH):
            data[r][c] = 1
    return True
```

### Method with numpy and skimage

```
import numpy as np
import random
import skimage.draw

MAP_WIDTH = 10
MAP_HEIGHT = 10

ROOM_LENGTH = 3
ROOM_HEIGHT = 3

NUM_ROOMS = 5


def create_map():
    # These values define how long you gonna to try to create a map
    outer_max_iteration = 10
    max_iteration = 1000

    outer_iteration = 0
    iteration = 0

    created_rooms = 0

    data = np.zeros((MAP_WIDTH, MAP_HEIGHT))
    while created_rooms < NUM_ROOMS and outer_iteration < outer_max_iteration:
        data = np.zeros((MAP_WIDTH, MAP_HEIGHT))
        while created_rooms < NUM_ROOMS and iteration < max_iteration:
            col = random.randint(0, MAP_WIDTH - ROOM_LENGTH)
            row = random.randint(0, MAP_HEIGHT - ROOM_HEIGHT)
            inserted = insert_room(data, col, row)
            created_rooms += inserted

            iteration += 1
        outer_iteration += 1
    if created_rooms < NUM_ROOMS:
        print("ERROR: Map cannot contain so many rooms!")
    print(data)
    return data


def insert_room(data, row, col) -> bool:
    # check bounds
    if row + ROOM_HEIGHT > MAP_HEIGHT or col + ROOM_LENGTH > MAP_WIDTH or row < 0 or col < 0:
        return False

    #: The rows of the polygon
    r = np.array([row, row, row + ROOM_HEIGHT, row + ROOM_HEIGHT])
    #: The columns of the polygon
    c = np.array([col, col + ROOM_LENGTH, col + ROOM_LENGTH, col])

    # create data where room should be created
    rr, cc = skimage.draw.polygon(r, c)

    #: check if room overlap with existing
    if not any(data[rr, cc]):
        data[rr, cc] = 1
        return True
    return False
```

example output:

```
[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [1. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 0.]
 [1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 0.]
 [1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 0.]
 [0. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 0.]
 [0. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
```

Comment: Although your help is greatly appreciated, I was looking for a solution that didnt require any other modules as im not experienced with numpy and it would involve changing other scripts to work with it. And efficiency is not my biggest priority. Could you propose a way to use your check for room intercept method using my code?

Comment: If you just don't want to work with numpy outside of the module you can cast the array at the end to a list with `return list(data)`. If you don't want to use numpy in general, you have to apply the stuff manually. I try to add it to my answer without numpy

Comment: @ClintK If you don't want to use numpy you just have to change the insert room method. the create_map stays the same. To your question, of how to ensure that you don't end in an endless loop

Comment: @ClintK I have added two versions without numpy and skimage. Are they the solution to your question?

Comment: yes the 2nd version does exactly what I was looking for thank you very much Uli.

Comment: Nevermind, I still cant do it. what you gave me is essentially the code I already had, what I wanted to know was how to implement it. I dont know how to use the true and false values to generate multiple rooms without getting a recursion depth error

Comment: Look at my `create_map` function. There are 2 variables with max_iterations. These prevent infinity recursion depth. My data variable is your grid variable.

Comment: Here is my attempt using your code: https://pastebin.com/4MCVE462 For some reason, this only creates one room. Also, what is the use of returning true or false when the room is inserted?

Comment: I return a boolean because the method only tries to insert a room. If it was successful True is returned, False otherwise. This is needed to count how many rooms were created.

Comment: 2. Your code, where you check if the room overlaps is wrong. You check if there is any 1 in the data array. But you should check if there is a one at the rooms position. This is why I used slicing and the for loop

Comment: Thank you for all your help, i figured it out. Code: https://pastebin.com/31zUejf4 I couldn't iterate using the any() so I just used the if statement and learning slicing like you suggested and it worked! If you want, you can add this to your answer